# How to read directories from git-fast-import's (aka is there a "cat-tree"?)

Tags: git

I'm working on a Git frontend which uses `git-fast-import` to make new commits to branches which are not currently checked out.  In some cases, I actually need to look at the branch's content.  Luckily there is the `cat-blob` command which lets me do just that for files, but for directories, this fails:

```
% git rev-parse refs/heads/master
5feba4d2856f545df951482c5ca9416c7202b555
% git fast-import                      
ls 5feba4d2856f545df951482c5ca9416c7202b555 numbers
040000 tree 2ca1672d50c9dbfe582dc53af3c7ce9891a7a664    numbers
cat-blob 2ca1672d50c9dbfe582dc53af3c7ce9891a7a664
fatal: Object 2ca1672d50c9dbfe582dc53af3c7ce9891a7a664 is a tree but a blob was expected.
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_11859
%
```

where `numbers` is a directory at the toplevel of the `master` branch and where the `ls ...` and `cat-blob ...` are the fast-import commands I typed and the rest is Git's reply to them.

I can often use `git cat-file -p refs/heads/master:numbers` to get the information I need, but sometimes this info is not uptodate with the changes that are being created in the fast-import, and additionally, it tends to be significantly slower because it can't reuse the active trees in the fast-import process.

Comment: Why do you not use `ls <treeish>`?  Are you looking for something to handle recursion for you?

Comment: AFAICT `ls ...` does not show me the content of the treee, it only gives me the SHA of the tree object.  The documentation of `git-fast-import` also indicates that `ls` only ever outputs a single line.

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, Jeff King gave me a solution which is not ideal but does let me get the contents of N directories without running N instances of Git.

He suggested I use `git cat-file --batch`.  Contrary to `cat-blob` in `fast-import` this does work on trees, tho the output is not pretty printed, and instead uses the following format:

```
tree = tree_entry*
tree_entry = mode SP path NUL sha1
mode = ascii mode, in octal (e.g., "100644")
path = <any byte except NUL>*
sha1 = <any byte>{20}
```

It's inconvenient for me to parse this, and it'd be better to get this output directly from `fast-import`, but in the mean time, it's better than nothing.